# Attaching Beads to Softbody Necklace

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I am designing a character for animation who is wearing a thread necklace with beads of varying sizes attached.

The softbody object is a mesh that boxes the thread, which has a surface deform modifier binded to the softbody object. Some vertices of the softbody are hooked to an empty, which currently sits inside one of the large beads at the back of the neck, but isn't connected to the bead.

The softbody works fine by itself -- it collides with the character and sits properly, but I can't figure out how to attach the beads correctly.

I tried hooking vertices from the softbody onto an empty and parenting the empty to the beads (might have just been extra steps), then enable rigid body on the beads, but the beads aren't restrained by the softbody so they'll just fall and glitch out the necklace.

[image: I would like to attach the beads to the necklace and simulate physics.]

Answer (score 1):

So I got over my laziness and joined all the beads and thread into one object, and updated the softbody collision object. I also added weight to the beads via vertex groups and made the vertex group the control point, and it seems to be working well right now!